# Display list of items in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple shopping list component to display the items in the state

How can I do this using a ul list

This is the code I have

I'm getting errors around items.map where it says its expecting a `:`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import uuid from 'uuid';

class ShoppingList extends Component {
    state = {
        items:[
            {id: uuid(), name: 'Eggs'},
            {id: uuid(), name: 'Bacon'},
            {id: uuid(), name: 'Beans'},
            {id: uuid(), name: 'Black Pudding'}
        ]
    }

    render(){
        const {items} = this.state;

        return(
            <button
                onClick={() =>{
                    const name = prompt('Enter Item');
                    if(name){
                        this.setState(state => ({
                            items: [...state.items, {id: uuid(), name}]
                        }));
                    }
                }}
            >
                Add Item
            </button>
            <ul>
                {items.map(({id,name}) => (
                    <li key={id}>
                        {name}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default ShoppingList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a top JSX element there. See the extra div I added.

**Edit**
I want to point @cr05s19xx's answer out about extracting the onClick handler. It is a good behavior to use this logic. Also, if extra `div` breaks some CSS then you can use `React.Fragment` again as @cr05s19xx suggested. So, the other answer probably is a better one than mine :)

```js
class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: "Eggs" },
      { id: 2, name: "Bacon" },
      { id: 3, name: "Beans" },
      { id: 4, name: "Black Pudding" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            const name = prompt("Enter Item");
            if (name) {
              this.setState(state => ({
                items: [...state.items, { id: uuid(), name }]
              }));
            }
          }}
        >
          Add Item
        </button>
        <ul>
          {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
            <li key={id}>{name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ShoppingList />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your output (unless you've trimmed it down), consider the following:

- Wrap the content inside `<React.Fragment>` since `render` can only render one Root element
- Move the onClick content outside to it's method, it is a generally accepted way to do it

Your output may now look like this

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuid';

class ShoppingList extends Component {
    state = {
        items: [
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Eggs' },
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Bacon' },
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Beans' },
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Black Pudding' }
        ]
    };

    buttonClicked = () => {
        const name = prompt('Enter item');
        if (name) {
            this.setState(state => ({
                items: [...state.items, { id: uuid(), name }]
            }));
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <button onClick={this.buttonClicked}>Add Item</button>
                <ul>
                    {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
                        <li key={id}>{name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

> Please run this and lemme know if it works or not